# Sanding floors where radiators interfere

Tags: flooring, sanding

We have radiant heat with approximately 8 " high metal radiators hanging off the lowest portion of some of the walls.  How would/could I use an edge sander?  Or do I just get as close as I can with the main sander and call it good enough?

Answer (score 1):

I thought I’d seen this question before on this site but I can’t find it

There is a sander made specifically for this problem [image]

Check with a floor finishing tool rental place. It is called a radiator edger or a toe kick edger sander.